# FullCalender not able to insert time into calender

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have been using the standard ISO date time format to insert into the full calender. When testing it, I was not able to enter the time into the calender even though the allDay field was set to false. The following is my php code.

```
$eventdt = date_format($eventdate,'c');
$eventet = date_format($eventend,'c'); 
 $buildjson = array('id'=>"$eventtest",'title' => "$eventtest", 'start' => "$eventdt", 'end' => "$eventet", 'allDay' => 'false', 'backgroundColor' => "$eventc");
array_push($jsonArray, $buildjson);
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

and the output of this code is

```
[{"id":"106","title":"106","start":"2013-07-17T11:00:00+02:00","end":"2013-07-18T14:00:00+02:00","allDay":"false","backgroundColor":"#FF0000"},{"id":"107","title":"107","start":"2013-07-19T10:45:00+02:00","end":"2013-07-20T14:15:00+02:00","allDay":"false","backgroundColor":"#FF0000"},{"id":"108","title":"108","start":"2013-07-22T10:45:00+02:00","end":"2013-07-22T14:15:00+02:00","allDay":"false","backgroundColor":"#FF0000"},{"id":"109","title":"109","start":"2013-07-22T10:45:00+02:00","end":"2013-07-22T14:15:00+02:00","allDay":"false","backgroundColor":"#D7DF01"}]
```

I saw that the datetime tag has an extra addition of +2:00 which is the local time zone. When I tried to insert the value manually within the script, the time is getting reflected on the calender

Manual insertion:

```
events: [   {
                title: 'class5 meeting',
                start: '2013-07-17T11:00:00',
                end: '2013-07-18T14:00:00',
                allDay: false,
                backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
                }
            ]
```

Is there any way that I can trim the date and send in the required values so that the values will be reflected?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might be that the `false` value for the 'allDay' field in your PHP generated JSON is a `String` whereas FullCalendar is expecting a `Bool`.

Try changing `$buildjson` as follows:

`$buildjson = array('id'=>"$eventtest",'title' => "$eventtest", 'start' => "$eventdt", 'end' => "$eventet", 'allDay' => false, 'backgroundColor' => "$eventc");` (note that `false`is not surrounded in quotes)